# ¿como redireccionar un link con vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

Tengo el siguiente link que corresponde al producto seleccionado que se muestra en mi carrito: (adjunto imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<w-link
        @click="openProductDetail()"
      >
        {{ row.item.name }}
      </w-link>
```

y en mi methods:

```
openProductDetail () {

    }
```

*Como deberia hacer el redireccionamiento en la funcion para que al hacer click en el link, me redirija a la pagina de productos (stock/products/) + el producto elegido por el cliente?*

esta url stock/products/ es una pantalla separada a la del carrito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mas "natural" es que la página de producto sea la misma para todos y utilizando `vue router` envíes un parámetro con la referencia/nombre del producto.

Te quedaría algo como:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'product', params: { productId: row.item.id }}">{{ row.item.name }}</router-link>
```